# How to list only outlets in intellisense declared in .h file on .m file intellisense?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

Iam a newbie in iOS Development.

outlets are displayed in intellisense on .m file if i type first characters but i want to see only list of outlets in intellisense like listing only methodnames of object .

Is there a way to list only outlets in intellisense when i want?

Do i always have to switch to .h file to see the list of outlets?

Comment: You mean by synthesise ? like getting outlet name in .m without using _ this

Comment: @iOSGeek yes . also in action methods

Answer (score 0):

.h file outlets

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *searchImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchbutton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

Use this line in .m file after implementation

```
@synthesize searchImage,searchbutton,mainLabel,activityIndicator;
```

To access them just write their name and use it

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
mainLabel.text = @"ss";
```